# How to stop UnityWebRequest Download in android?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to stop UnityWebRequest download immediately with a button in android application.

Stopping coroutine with `StopCoroutine("downLoadFromServer");` does not stop UnityWebRequest.
I tried using `UnityWebRequest.Dispose();` or `UnityWebRequest.Abort();` with no success.
Below is the download i'm trying to stop.

```
private IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{

    var url = "https://example.com/app.apk"; 
    var savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data", "app.apk");              

    using (var uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        uwr.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test:test")));
        uwr.SendWebRequest();

        while (!uwr.isDone)
        {
            progressText.text = $"Progress: {uwr.downloadProgress:P}";
            yield return null;
        }

        var yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

        progressText.text = $"Done downloading. Size: {yourBytes.Length}";

        //Create Directory if it does not exist
        var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(savePath);
        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryName))
        {
             Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
            progressText.text = "Created Dir";
        }

        try
        {
            //Now Save it
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, yourBytes);
            Debug.Log("Saved Data to: " + savePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
            progressText.text = "Saved Data";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Failed To Save Data to: " + savePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
            Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
            progressText.text = "Error Saving Data";
        }
    }

    //Install APK
    installApp(savePath);
}
```

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Can you add the code of how you start the routine and where you try to abort it? Did you try `StopAllCoroutines`? `Abort` should actually do what you want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: Stopping the Coroutine does not cancel the `UnityWebRequest`, you are just not keeping track of it anymore.

Actually [`UnityWebRequest.Abort`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Abort.html) should do exactly that

> If in progress, halts the `UnityWebRequest` as soon as possible.
>
> This method may be called at any time. If the `UnityWebRequest` has not already completed, the `UnityWebRequest` will halt uploading or downloading data as soon as possible. Aborted `UnityWebRequests` are considered to have encountered a system error. Either the `isNetworkError` or the `isHttpError` property will return `true` and the `error` property will be `"User Aborted"`.

However this makes ofcourse only sense if you actually check the result of the request which currently you aren't doing and you should do anyway!

A way to use it would be to make the `uwr` a class wide field so you can access it from somewhere else and as said actually add a check if the download succeeded:

```
private UnityWebRequest uwr;

private IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{
    ...

    // NOTE: Remove the var so the class field uwr is assigned to, not only
    // a local variable
    using(uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(...))
    {
        ...

        // Always check if a request was actually successful before continuing
        if(uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uwr.error))
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Download Failed with {uwr.responseCode}, reason: {uwr.error}", this);

            progressText.text = $"Download Failed: {uwr.error}";

            // Cancel this Coroutine
            yield break;
        }

        var yourBytes = uwr.downloadHandler.data;

        ...
    }

    //Install APK
    installApp(savePath);
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
public void AbortDownload()
{
    if(uwr != null && !uwr.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Aborting download ...", this);
        uwr.Abort();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Not downloading, nothing to do ...", this);
    }
}
```

which should make the download "fail" and thereby also finish the Coroutine

Comment: I don't know why but still does not stop the download.

Comment: @Oldhuntersblood what happens instead? Are you sure the `Abort` is called? Did you try to [debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: I edited        `if(uwr.isHttpError || uwr.isNetworkError || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uwr.error))
        {
            progressText.text = $"Download Failed: {uwr.error}";

            // Cancel this Coroutine
            yield break;                                                                         
            Debug.Log("Break Happened");
        }`      but apparently when I call `public void AbortDownload()`  "Break Happened" never shows.

Comment: yes because you have put the log after `yield break;` ... `yield break;` is like the `return` of a void method ... anything after it is not executed anymore

Comment: Putting it before and closing myserver apache "break Happened"" shows up and download stops.  Aparrently doesn't show up with public void AbortDownload() and download continues.

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `var` before `uwr`? Otherwise the `Abort` will never happen indeed. I recommend to rather use `public void AbortDownload(){ if(uwr != null){ Debug.Log("Abborting download", this); uwr.Abort(); } else { Debug.Log("No download, nothing to do", this);}}` if you are not sure

Comment: Debug "No download nothing to do".   So it cant detect uwr?

Comment: @Oldhuntersblood as said my guess is you have `using(var uwr = ...)` which hides(overrules) the class field with the same name `uwr` so it is never assigned to but only the local `uwr` variable. Remove the `var`

Comment: That was it! I had to remove var! Thank you for everything!